# Why does the equation follow?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

From the inequalities $$\sum_{k=1}^N\int_{k-1 }^k v^r dv\leq\sum_{1\leq t\leq N}t^r\leq \sum_{k=1}^N\int_{k }^{k+1} v^r dv $$ it follows $$\sum_{1\leq t\leq N}t^r=\int_{1}^N v^r dv+\mathcal{O}(N^r) .$$ I do not understand the term $\mathcal O(N^r)$ . Should it not be $\mathcal O(N^{r+1})=\int_N^{N+1}v^r dv?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That term is actually of the order $(N+1)^{r+1} - N^{r+1} \asymp N^r$.
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r+1} = \int_0^1 v^r \, dv \le \sum_{t=1}^N t^r - \int_1^N v^r \, dv
&\le\int_N^{N+1} v^r \, dv
\\
&= \frac{1}{r+1}((N+1)^{r+1} - N^{r+1} )
\\
&= \frac{1}{r+1} \sum_{k=1}^{r} \binom{r+1}{k} N^k
\\
&= O(N^r)
\end{align}

Comment: thanks for your help. I do not understand how you get the first inequality .

Comment: @AnabolicHorse Sorry, corrected my mistake.

Comment: ,thanks a lot for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would use another identity: rewriting the inequalities as
$$\int_{0}^N v^r\,\mathrm dv=\int_{0}^1 v^r\,\mathrm dv+\int_{1}^N v^r\,\mathrm dv\leq\sum_{1\leq t\leq N}t^r\leq \int_{1}^{N+1}v^r\,\mathrm dv=\int_1^N v^r\,\mathrm dv+\int_N^{N+1}v^r\,\mathrm dv, $$
whence
$$\int_{0}^1 v^r\,\mathrm dv \leq\sum_{1\leq t\leq N}t^r-\int_{1}^N v^r\,\mathrm dv\leq \int_{N}^{N+1} v^r\,\mathrm dv. $$
Now, by a high-school formula
\begin{align}
\int_{N}^{N+1}\!\!\! v^r\,\mathrm dv&=\frac{(N+1)^{r+1}-N^{r+1}}{r+1}=\frac{N+1-N}{r+1}\bigl((N+1)^r+(N+1)^{r-1}N+\dots+(N+1)N^{r-1}+N^r\bigr)\\
&=\frac1{r+1} \,O(N^r)\quad\text{since each}\quad (N+1)^{r-i}N^i\sim_\infty N^r \\
&=O(N^r).
\end{align}

Comment: thanks for your help.